# Firestore update multiple records

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents that I wish to update following this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

I wish to increment a field in each doc by a value of two.

```
const collection = db.collection('groups').where('age', '> 20', right).get()
    .then(response => {
        response.docs.forEach((doc) => {
            let updateGroup = doc.update(
                {
                    days: doc.days + 2;
                }
            );
        })
    })
```

When I run the code above I receive the following error:
TypeError: doc.update is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `doc` variable is not a [DocumentReference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html).  It's a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html).  You can see from the API documentation that it doesn't have an `update()` method.  If you want the DocumentReference from a snapshot, use its `ref` property.

```
doc.ref.update(...)
```